# How to filter/reduce array of object with specific dynamically keys based in other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter, reduce

I'm gonna explain my problem. I don't have time to think more about that and I have a blocker and I can't figure it out so any help will be appreciated. For example, I have an array of objects (it can be array with 100+ elements):

```
  const arr = [
    { value: '1', id: 1, number: 1, other: 'example', data: '6' },
    { value: '2', id: 2, number: 2, other: 'example', data: '7' },
    { value: '3', id: 3, number: 3, other: 'example', data: '8' },
    { value: '4', id: 4, number: 4, other: 'example', data: '9' },
    { value: '5', id: 5, number: 4, other: 'example', data: '10' },
  ];
```

and in the other array I have strings which contain specific keys like that:

```
  const keys = ['value', 'id', 'number'];
```

and my problem is that I want to return the variable `arr` only contains objects based on values on the `keys` variable. Something like that:

```
 const arr = [
    { value: '1', id: 1, number: 1 },
    { value: '2', id: 2, number: 2 },
    { value: '3', id: 3, number: 3 },
    { value: '4', id: 4, number: 4 },
    { value: '5', id: 5, number: 4 },
  ];
```

I would like to have it dynamically because values in the `keys` variable are not constant and can be a `value`, `other`, `data` or only `data` or `id` and `other` etc.

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Iterating over the array is a given, thus the issue is removing not needed keys from an object. You can either create a new object and set its props by iterating over `keys`, or use `delete` to remove them from the existing object. The former means you'll want to use `arr.map()` while the latter is a job for `arr.forEach()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a function which will return based on keys array and use that function to map..

```
const arr = [
        { value: '1', id: 1, number: 1, other: 'example', data: '6' },
        { value: '2', id: 2, number: 2, other: 'example', data: '7' },
        { value: '3', id: 3, number: 3, other: 'example', data: '8' },
        { value: '4', id: 4, number: 4, other: 'example', data: '9' },
        { value: '5', id: 5, number: 4, other: 'example', data: '10' },
      ];

    const keys = ['value', 'id', 'number'];

    function pick(obj, keys){
        let result = {};
        for(let i=0; i<keys.length; i++){
            result[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i]];
        }
        return result;
    }

    let finalArr = arr.map( value => pick(value,keys));

    console.log(finalArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using `Array.prototype.map()` and a `reduce`.

```js
const arr = [
    { value: '1', id: 1, number: 1, other: 'example', data: '6' },
    { value: '2', id: 2, number: 2, other: 'example', data: '7' },
    { value: '3', id: 3, number: 3, other: 'example', data: '8' },
    { value: '4', id: 4, number: 4, other: 'example', data: '9' },
    { value: '5', id: 5, number: 4, other: 'example', data: '10' },
];

const keys = ['value', 'id', 'number'];

const res = arr.map(item => keys.reduce((acc, key) => ({...acc, [key]: item[key]}), {}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height: 100% !important; top: 0;}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Sorry I didn't check that It creates more objects in the array and I needed everything in the one object. I have to change the acceptance of the answer but your answer is still good ;) Thank you very much again.

Comment: Sorry for your inconvinience. I've updated my code.

Comment: Thanks again, I like to reduce + map than for loop so I change it again :) Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome again. But we should encourage the newcomers more.  As his answer is also right.

Comment: You are right. So If you do not mind I gave him the best answer.